# OpenGL - 3D Rotation around Local Axes

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, rotation

Background: 
I have been working on the problem of 3D object rotation around its local axes, using OpenGL. After having extensively searched on different forums for a mathematical model for updating the axes as x/y/z rotations happen, I found this to be the most helpful resource.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/camera_class_tutorial/18010/

The Problem:
I am currently stumbling upon a rather trivial issue. An example from the resource mentioned above does a 45 degree rotation around y-axis; hence x- and z-axes need to be updated. The new x-axis is calculate as (0.707, 0, 0.707), which makes sense. The z-axis is (-0.707, 0, 0.707), which is also intuitive. The corresponding gl commands are:

```
glRotatef(x_rot, 0.707, 0, 0.707);
glRotatef(y_rot, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(z_rot, -0.707, 0, 0.707);
```

Now I am rotating first around y-axis by 45 degrees. After that the x-rotation looks good. It is around the updated (local) axis, as intended.

Then, I remove x-rotation; but when I apply z-rotation it does not look right. It is not rotating along the local z-axis. The axis looks correct mathematically, but I am not sure what could be going wrong graphically.

EDIT:

The example is around the middle of that page.

Comment: "but when I apply z-rotation it does not look right" How so? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: the rotation is not around the new z-axis. Rather it looks to be happening around a different (random) axis.

Comment: Are you ensuring that you're pushing the current matrix before applying the rotation? Generally you'd call glPushMatrix(), reset the current modelview matrix, then call glPopMatrix() to ensure that you're not getting any other matrices in your rotation.

You'll also want to ensure you're not encountering gimbal lock, since you're using Euler angles.

Either way, we'd need to see more of your code in the question to be able to comment on the problem.

Comment: @stix: push/pop matrices - that's all taken care of. I am pretty sure I am not running into a gimbal lock since I am rotating around only 2 axes.

Comment: @Iceman: Do you recall some linear algebra from school? If so, do yourself a favor, make sure that your view matrix is identity, and printf the current matrices to console after each step by float p[16]; glGet(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, p);  and simply read the values you look for from the matrix you get. Keep in mind that OpenGL uses column-major order.